# I want to run Vue app frontend in wordpress using vite

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I want to run wp backend with a vue front end I am using a vps to do most of the things and doing git at the moment.

I have installed an empty vite project inside `twentytwentythree` theme of wordpress.

I want to run the default front-end of vite instead of this. What files do I need to add and remove? There are very few and mostly old resources on the internet at the moment.

The following is my project structure I had 9 wp installations in my vps and I intilized the htdocs folder in my git directly.

[image]